# Only a type can be imported drools

Tags: liferay, drools

I am using Drools and Liferay, and I am trying to insert in the BD a user when the rule was true, but Drools doesn't let me import a package. I don't have a .drl class, I pass a string to execute drools. This is my code:

Code drools:

```
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.BooleanClause;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.BooleanClauseOccur;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.BooleanClauseFactoryUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.BooleanQuery;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.BooleanQueryFactoryUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.Document;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.Field;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.Hits;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.Indexer;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.IndexerRegistryUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.SearchContext;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.GetterUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.KeyValuePair;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.StringUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.Validator;
import com.liferay.portal.model.Address;
import com.liferay.portal.model.Group;
import com.liferay.portal.model.Contact;
import com.liferay.portal.model.User;
import com.liferay.portal.service.AddressLocalServiceUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil;
import com.liferay.portlet.asset.model.AssetEntry;
import com.liferay.portlet.asset.service.AssetEntryLocalServiceUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.model.User;
import com.liferay.portal.security.auth.PrincipalThreadLocal;
import com.liferay.portal.security.permission.PermissionChecker;
import com.liferay.portal.security.permission.PermissionCheckerFactoryUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.security.permission.PermissionThreadLocal;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ObjectValuePair;
import com.liferay.portlet.expando.model.ExpandoBridge;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.segmentationPortlet.controller.prova;

rule "Initialize Rules"
salience 1000
when
    user : User(); 
then
end

rule "Rule_1"
when 
    userRule_2: User(emailAddress == "test@liferay.com")
user: User();
then
    prova p;
    p.classification(user,"SegmentUser");
end
```

Code to execute Drools;
    //rule is a string that have Drools's code.
    ThemeDisplay td = (ThemeDisplay) actionRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
    User user = td.getUser();
    facts.add(new Fact  ("user", user));

```
RulesResourceRetriever rulesResourceRetriever = new RulesResourceRetriever(new                                          StringResourceRetriever(rule), String.valueOf(RulesLanguage.                 RulesEngineUtil.update(domainName, rulesResourceRetriever,      PortalClassLoaderUtil.getClassLoader());
RulesEngineUtil.execute(domainName, facts, Query.createStandardQuery(),      PortalClassLoaderUtil.getClassLoader());`
```

prova.java code:
    package com.segmentationPortlet.controller;

```
import com.liferay.counter.service.CounterLocalServiceUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.model.User;
import com.segmentationPortlet.model.UserRule;
import com.segmentationPortlet.service.UserRuleLocalServiceUtil;
import com.segmentationPortlet.service.persistence.UserRulePK;

public class prova {
    public void classification(User user, String segmentValue)  {
        try {
            UserRule ur = null ;
            long id1 = CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment(UserRule.class.getName());
            long id2 = CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment(UserRule.class.getName());
            UserRulePK u = new UserRulePK(id1, id2); 
            ur= UserRuleLocalServiceUtil.createUserRule(u);
            Long id = (long) 1234;
            ur.setUserId(user.getUserId());
            ur.setRuleId(id);
            ur.setSegment(segmentValue);
            UserRuleLocalServiceUtil.addUserRule(ur);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 }`
```

When I try to execute I have this error:

Caused by: com.liferay.portal.kernel.bi.rules.RulesEngineException: Error importing : 'com.segmentationPortlet.controller.prova'
Error importing : 'com.segmentationPortlet.controller.Classification.classification'
Error importing : 'com.segmentationPortlet.controller.GetCustomAttribute.getCustomAttribute'
[ function getCustomAttributegetCustomAttribute (line:53): Only a type can be imported. com.segmentationPortlet.controller.prova resolves to a package
 ]
[ function classificationclassification (line:35): Only a type can be imported. com.segmentationPortlet.controller.prova resolves to a package
 ]
[ function getCustomAttributegetCustomAttribute (line:53): Only a type can be imported. com.segmentationPortlet.controller.prova resolves to a package
 ]

Any idea abaout how I can resolve the problem?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.
this code is generated dynamically and executes  then I have to create a new project, make the .jar and move it to /tomcat/lib/ext, to permet Drools access it.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The problem is that the name of your class doesn't follow Java's good practices: class names start with a capital letter. Drools seems to take this pretty seriously :)</strike>

Change your class name to **P**rova and it should work fine.

EDIT: Forget about this response. I did a mistake while testing this scenario. See my other response instead

Hope it helps,

Comment: I check the import, and it's correct. I try to add the class to the classpath doing this:
Click in the project name, "Properties" -> "Java Build Path" and in "Libraries" click "Add Class Folder" and select the folder /src/com/controller that it's where the class "Prova.java" is. But when I execute the code I have the same error. And yes,  I am using Drools 5.5.0, but I don't have this error because the code cannot execute yet. I'va tried put de path to Prova.java in the classpath of Windows but it doesn't work too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start again. I managed to reproduce the error message by importing an unexisting class in my drl. So, please double check that the import in your .drl file points to the correct 'prova' class. Also make that the class is accessible in runtime by drools' engine (The class must be in the classpath).

By the way, which version of drools are you using? According to 5.5.0, the RHS of your second rule should fail during compilation time with the following message: "Rule Compilation error The local variable p may not have been initialized'

Hope it helps,

Comment: I check the import, and it's correct. I try to add the class to the classpath doing this: Click in the project name, "Properties" -> "Java Build Path" and in "Libraries" click "Add Class Folder" and select the folder /src/com/controller that it's where the class "Prova.java" is. But when I execute the code I have the same error. And yes, I am using Drools 5.5.0, but I don't have this error because the code cannot execute yet.
Thanks.